# Error plotting heatmap: 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

Tags: r, plot, error-handling, heatmap

I tried to write a piece of R code to create a heatmap using the mtcars dataset. However, even after trying other datasets, I keep on getting the following error:

```
`Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

This error does not allow me to get the graph plotted in R studio or to knit the Rmd file
`

Below you can find the function I wrote. Originally, the function was more elaborate, but I get the same error even after trimming the function as below.

```
library(gplots)
Heatmap <- function(InputMatrix, OutputPlotName){
  #Make the Heatmap
  Heatmapp <- heatmap.2(InputMatrix
          )
  plot(Heatmapp)
  }
```

Here is when I try to apply the function (and get the error).

```
Heatmap(InputMatrix=as.matrix(mtcars), OutputPlotName="heatmap")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Heatmapp` object has different components to it and is stored as a list in R, which doesn't have a `plot` method defined. Try this instead:

```r
Heatmap <- function(InputMatrix, OutputPlotName){
  #Make the Heatmap
  Heatmapp <- heatmap.2(InputMatrix
  )
  invisible(Heatmapp)
}
```

Using `invisible()` returns the plot, without printing the rest of the output stored in the list.

Comment: Thanks! With your suggestion, I do not get the error anymore. However, I still cannot visualize the plot in Rstudio or in the knitted Rmd file. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Maybe try switching the `invisible()` to a `return()`, and then changing the code block options to hide the rest of the output?